# Applying IF conditional to 3 rows and returning another value of another cell if the condition met

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have 3 cells in a row filled with Usernames, and another cell in the same row filled with time, I want to make columns with these usernames Id and if the username Id found any of the rows then print the time in the formula cell. is there any way to achieve this? I tried `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP` the fail was painful.

I have attached an image as an example and I really appreciate your help as its very important for me.

[image: Spreadsheet example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **G2** cell and drag to the right, then drag down:

```
=IF($A2=G$1, $E2, IF($B2=G$1, $E2, IF($C2=G$1, $E2, "out")))
```

[image: 0]

---

one cell solution:

paste in **G2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), {
 IF(A2:A=G1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=G1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=G1, E2:E, "out"))), 
 IF(A2:A=H1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=H1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=H1, E2:E, "out"))), 
 IF(A2:A=I1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=I1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=I1, E2:E, "out"))),
 IF(A2:A=J1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=J1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=J1, E2:E, "out")))}, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help for the 2nd time. it works but needs to edit that I need it to be working on rows not columns, like if user1 (G1) was found between A2:C2 then print the time in E2 in G2 which is User1. I appreciate your help so much

Comment: not sure I understood you. can you explain in more detail why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I want the formula to be like: if G1=A2:C2 then copy E2 in G2 ... can you help me to phrase it in formula plz.

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(A2:A=G1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=G1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=G1, E2:E, ))),
               IF(A2:A=H1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=H1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=H1, E2:E, ))), 
               IF(A2:A=I1, E2:E, IF(B2:B=I1, E2:E, IF(C2:C=I1, E2:E, )))})` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HhcU.png

Comment: Can we apply this on rows not columns?? as I want to know in which time the user1, for example, was working?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xd9xHLLzRO8BlwL4yNziwn00d6xh5lUKqGxWun6GY80/edit#gid=0

Comment: or perhaps you want this? `=ARRAYFORMULA({
 SUM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(A2:C<>"", "♦"&A2:C&"♥"&E2:E, ),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1='"&G1&"'")),
 SUM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(A2:C<>"", "♦"&A2:C&"♥"&E2:E, ),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1='"&H1&"'")),
 SUM(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(A2:C<>"", "♦"&A2:C&"♥"&E2:E, ),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1='"&I1&"'"))})` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvLrB.png

Comment: I updated the spreadsheet, excuse me if i cant deliver the idea. and thank you so much.

Comment: One final thing, it would be amazing if achievable. can we calculate the accumulated time of the user spent on depending on the hours listed?

Comment: I update the sheet with the working hours for easy understanding. thank you very much

Comment: Im sorry not this. i mean if we have times like in the sheet, like 23.15, 22:10, 21,40 is there anyway to count how many hours within alot of times like this? like between 23:15 and 21.40 is about 2.15 hours.

Comment: can you show me how you imagine output to look like?